# VBA: looping column cells through variable

Tags: excel, vba, loops, variables, excel-2010

I am new to this VBA. I want to run a loop with some conditions in it but i don't want to use the cell() syntax, instead I want to use the variable and different variable for different columns.
like for example instead of using "if cell(1, i) < cell(2, i-1)" i want to use "if varA < varB-1" where varA=cell(1, i), varB=cell(2, i) and varB-1=cell(2, i-1).

P.S.: the data set is large, like thousands of rows and 30-40 columns, and has to check multiple conditions repeatedly. so kindly consider it too.

```
Dim i As Integer
i = 1
Do While i <= 10
if cell(1, i) < cell(2, i-1)
MsgBox Result
Loop
```

Comment: There is no `Cell()` function in Excel VBA; it should be `Cells()`. VBA variables may not function as you anticipate. Could you please provide the reason why the condition `If Cells(1, i) < Cells(2, i-1)` doesn't meet your requirements?

Comment: Using a variable like `varB-1` would result in the value being deducted 1, i.e. if varB = 50 -> varB-1 = 49. What you can use is a range variable and use `.Offset(i,j)` with `.Offset(1,2)` meaning the cell 1 row and 2 columns further than what you set the range variable to.

Comment: @taller yes, cells, but not imp here. and If Cells(1, i) < Cells(2, i-1) is comparison of 2 cells, i need to do this alogwith 5-10 similar conditions for 14 columns across hundreds of rows across tens of sheets. so remembering every column holds what value in each sheet is quite hectic.

Comment: @Notus_Panda exactly my thought about that if varB = 50 -> varB-1 = 49. hence trying to find how to do it in the most easy to read way as i wont be the only one to use this. and i dont think offset can help me to do what i want to achieve here.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the values from a range into an array variable e.g.

```
Sub demo()
    
    'Must be declared as Variant
    Dim arr As Variant
    
    'Use explict range rather than UsedRange - this is a demo only
    arr = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Value
    
    Dim cl As Long, rw As Long
    
    For rw = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
        For cl = 1 To UBound(arr, 2)
            Debug.Print "Row", rw, "Column", cl, "Value", arr(rw, cl)
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: had similar thought with simple arrays but arrays are a bit slow. hence looking for a better solution. because i have to do multiple conditions across various columns, rows and sheets.

Comment: Arrays are a bit slow? We must be dealing with different arrays then..

Comment: @AkhileshKumar Arrays are not slow. Using cells is slow. Anything where the thing you are examining is held in memory is going to be "fast" in comparison.
What on earth makes you think that arrays are slow?

Comment: you guys have clearly not read my reply to the taller below my question. if you read it you will understand i have to deal with huge amount of data,, as the values mentioned in that comment is just a sample, this needs to be implemented on a much larger data. so kindly understand the situation properly before you comment next time. in case you still have some doubts, you can try some runtime performance comparison on large set of data and check for yourself that how fast arrays are on large data sets on multiple conditions.

Comment: made an edit in my question, i hope you understand now what issue i actually am trying to solve.

Comment: My comments stand. Arrays are not slow. I don't need to do some runtime performance comparison because I do this on a regular basis across tens of thousands of rows.
You also seem to be confused over how much data you have - thousands of rows over 30-40 columns or hundreds of rows over 14 columns across 10s of sheets.
The only alternative I can suggest is to use Power Query instead of VBA